# How do I find secret mercurial revisions?

Tags: search, mercurial, phase

I work on a lot of projects and sometimes I'd prefer to just delete my local repositories. However, I am limited in this by my occasional use of the secret phase (as I need to check how my repository differs from the server).

Is there a search I can use to find changesets in the secret phase or do I have to revert to (the slow)

```
hg log --debug | grep secret -B 2 -A 15
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See `hg help revsets` for information on how to specify ranges of revisions. This should do the trick:

```
hg log -r "secret()"
```